# PHP: Filter MYSQL array

Tags: php, mysql, browser, operating-system, counter

I'm developing an visits counter and I'd like to increase a number depending on the browser and the operating system.

For example:

```
Firefox     Mac OS X 

Safari      Mac OS X 

Firefox     Mac OS X

Firefox     Linux
```

Then the website would display

> Safari on Mac OS X     1 visit
>
> Firefox on Mac OS X    2 visits
>
> Firefox on Linux       1 visit

There are a lot of browsers and operating systems combinations, then I'd like to use an algorithm that will calculate that easily. The data is retrieved from a MYSQL database. Does anyone knows a good way to do it?

Comment: What exactly are you storing in the DB? `Firefox     Mac OS X ` is that what you are storing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT browser, os, COUNT(*) as c FROM table GROUP BY browser, os;
```

Answer (score 1):

The function [get_browser](http://nl2.php.net/get_browser) will return a rather large array with all the information it can know about the user.

You should put this array in a database, probably with a column for each piece of information that get_browser() returns:

```
  $browser = get_browser()
  print_r($browser);

  foreach ($browser as $key => $information) { // You may want to use array_walk for this, wich is harder to read in a simple example.
    $browser_clean[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($information); //DO NOT FORGET TO SANITIZE, ppl can spoof the browserstrings and open up SQL injection holes!
  }
  //You probably want some slightly cleaner and better way to talk to the Database then boiling up some ugly SQL-string, though.
  mysql_query('INSERT INTO browserstats (parent, platform, browser, ...restofyourfields) VALUES ('. $browser_clean['parent'] .','. $browser_clean['platform'] .','. $browser_clean['browser'] .'...restofthefields)')
```

;